# Поддерживает ли SslStream (или сам LSASS) TLS compression?

Tags: c#, .net

Поддерживает ли `SslStream` (или сам LSASS) TLS compression? Если да - то какими опциями рееста\настройками ОС\вызовами из кода можно манипулировать (включать\отключать) сжатием?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скажу коротко:

### Нет

SslStream в сочетании с протоколом TLS 1.2 поддерживает только **null compression**. Попробуйте отослать запрос из SslStream и посмотреть, какие есть "Compression Methods" при **Client Hello**, там будет только **Comperssion Method: null.**

Сжатие данных в TLS не поддерживается во многих современных библиотеках, да и не только в .NET, потому что его поддержка лишена смысла из-за **аспектов безопасности** и здравых соображений. Да, это помогает медленным каналам, но здесь появляется уязвимость..

Стандарт **[TLS 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-14)**, который сейчас находится в стадии "черновика" предусматривает удаление такого понятие как **сжатие данных**.

Все это связано с тем, что появилась различные атаки на SSL/TLS при использовании сжатия, одна из них называется **CRIME** (*Compression Ratio Info-leak Made Easy*), хотя есть еще **BREACH** (*Browser Reconnaissance & Exfiltration via Adaptive Compression of Hypertext*)

### Алгоритм атаки

Если говорить кратко, то атакующий должен использовать сначала первичную атаку «**Man In The Middle**» (MITM), т.е Хакер должен перехватывать весь пользовательский трафик, неважно как, пусть даже разрезав ваш кабель и подсоединив его к своему компьютеру.

Добавляя в него свои данные, он отправляет запросы на сервер. Алгоритм сжатия в силу своих особенностей, при повторении части текста естественно сжимает его.

После отправки данных на сервер, хакер смотрит за длиной сообщения и если **оно уменьшилось**, значит подобрана правильная последовательность. Тем самым можно подбирать отдельные строки и параметры в запросе, например, значения куки. Но есть ограничения — часть данных нужно знать, чтобы от неё начать подбирать остальную информацию.

В атаке не взламывается шифр, не подбирается ключ шифрования, а подбираются значения зашифрованного текста.

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить один момент - TLS 1.0 и 1.1 имеют схожее поведение?

Comment: @Alexis Конечно, от версии протокола не зависит. Если вы посмотрите спецификацию TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, то в спецификациях есть такое понятие, как Compression Methods и в них ничего не меняется в этом плане. Поддержка Comperssion Methods отключена или не реализована на уровне библиотеки через которую осуществляется подключение. Изменение SecurityProtocol ничего не изменит.

Comment: По сути, если очень надо, можно создать какой-нибудь DeflateStream, кодировать вручную на одной стороне и раскодировать вручную на другой переданные данные.

Comment: Понятно, благодарю за наводку, вот только код на серверной стороне - не мой. Вообще в SslStream много ресурсов уходит на проверки и внутреннее логирование, скорее всего буду менять транспорт, хотя не хотелось бы( p.s. выдам награду как пройдет период холда, примерно через сутки. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alexis Хм, безопасность всегда требует дополнительных ресурсов, в общем случае применение криптографии в протоколах SSL/TLS значительно снижает производительность приложений, зато обеспечивает надежную защиту передачи данных. Спасибо за интересный вопрос :)